# updating tkinter window (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, tkinter

Good Afternoon all,

I've been working on a contact-book program for a school project. I've got all of the underlying code complete. However I've decided to take it one step further and implement a basic interface. I am trying to display all of the contacts using the code snippet below:

```
    elif x==2:
    phonebook_data= open(data_path,mode='r',encoding = 'utf8')
    if os.stat(data_path)[6]==0:
        print("Your contact book is empty.")
    else:
        for line in phonebook_data:
            data= eval(line)
        for k,v in sorted(data.items()):
            x= (k + ": " + v)
            from tkinter import *
            root = Tk()
            root.title("Contacts")
            text = Text(root)
            text.insert('1.0', x)
            text.pack()
            text.update()
    root.mainloop()
    phonebook_data.close()
```

The program works, however every contact opens in a new window. I would like to display all of the same information in a single loop. I'm fairly new to tkinter and I apologize if the code is confusing at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the top of the snippet could be much more efficient:

`phonebook_data= open(data_path,mode='r',encoding = 'utf8')` should be changed to
`phonebook_data = open(data_path)`.

Afterwards, just use:

```
contents = phonebook_data.read()
if contents == "":       # Can be shortened to `if not contents:`
    print("Your contact book is empty.")
```

And by the way, it's good practice to close the file as soon as you're done using it.

```
phonebook_data = open(data_path)
contents = phonebook_data.read()
phonebook_data.close()

if contents == "":
    print("Your contact book is empty.")
```

Now for your graphics issue. Firstly, you should consider whether or not you really need a graphical interface for this application. If so:

```
# Assuming that the contact book is formatted `Name` `Number` (split by a space)
name_number = []
for line in contents.split("\n"): # Get each line
    name, number = line.split()
    name_number.append(name + ": " + number) # Append a string of `Name`: `Number` to the list
name_number.sort() # Sort by name

root = Tk()
root.title("Contact Book")
text = Text(root)
text.pack(fill=BOTH)
text.insert("\n".join(name_number))
root.mainloop()
```

Considering how much I have shown you, it would probably be considered cheating for you to use it. Do some more research into the code though, it didn't seem like the algorithm would work in the first place.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for all of the pointers! I'll do my best to implement some of the simplifications and I'll start working my way through the last code. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3185748: keep the `encoding=utf-8` parameter if you know that the files are encoded in utf-8. If `encoding` is not specified `open()` uses `locale.getprefferedencoding()` that might return different character encoding and corrupt your data.